# Why matches grep pattern '[^a-z0-9\.\/_\-\ +@)(&]' matches '-'

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to find files with ridiculous filenames. I'm using this command:

```
find . -type f | egrep -i '[^a-z0-9\.\/_\-\ +@)(&]'
```

but I'm a little bit dumstruck because it matches filenames containing the minus character '-'. Why? And how to fix that?

Edit:
Procedure to reproducibly verify this behaviour:

I created a test file named testfile, containing just a minus sign

```
$ hexdump -C testfile

00000000  2d                                                |-|
```

```
egrep -i '[^a-z0-9\.\/_\-\ +@)(&]' testfile
```

matches this minus sign.

Comment: Could you give an example of file that match but shouldn't?

Comment: I’m with Toto, please provide an unaltered example, copied directly from your terminal. Just because it looks like a minus(/dash/hyphen) doesn’t mean it’s ASCII character 0x45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyphen has a special meaning in a character class, it denotes a range of character.

Put the hyphen at the end of the character class, and remove useless escape:

```
find . -type f | egrep -i '[^a-z0-9./_ +@)(&-]'
```

Comment: Thx a lot! That fixes it. But Why, oh why can't I see why?